# Get data array from sqlite database and post to API via json object... can be possible?

Tags: json, sqlite, android-studio, post, retrofit2

newbie here... i was developing app that send my data to api via retrofit. my code was working but it sends 1 data input only at the time.... in my case, i've like to do is I want to get more saved data in my sqlite (example 5 data saved) and send it all on api via json object.

This is my Activity:

```
                 DatabaseHelper databaseHelper2 = new 
                 DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    SQLiteDatabase db2 = 
                    databaseHelper2.getWritableDatabase();
                    Cursor cursor = 
                    databaseHelper2.retrieveSettingFromLocalDatabase(db2);

                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        ADDRESS = 

    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_ADDRESS));
                        PORT = 
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_PORT));
                        TIMEINTERVAL=cursor.getString
    (cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_TIME_INTERVAL));
                    }
                    portInts=Integer.parseInt(PORT);

                    MapDetails mapDetails = new MapDetails(gg, lat, lon, 
        well, "0", portInts); //Datas ive get to send in api

                    List<MapDetails> data = new ArrayList<>();
                    data.add(mapDetails);

                    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl("http://" + ADDRESS + ":" + PORT) 
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

                    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

                    Api locate = retrofit.create(Api.class);

                    Call<MapDetails> call = locate.mapDetailLocation(data);     

                    call.enqueue(new Callback<MapDetails>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<MapDetails> call, Response<MapDetails> response) {
                            Snackbar.make(view, "" + response,
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                            Snackbar.make(view, "" + t.getMessage(),
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

                        }
                    });
```

This is my code in API:

```
 public interface Api {
   @POST("/api/Database/NewLocation")
      Call<MapDetails> mapDetailLocation(@Body List<MapDetails> mapDetails)

 }
```

This is my sample Client:

```
     public class MapDetails {
        @SerializedName("SerialNumber")
        @Expose
        private String SerialNumber;
        @SerializedName("Coordinate1")
        @Expose
        private String Coordinate1;
        @SerializedName("Coordinate2")
        @Expose
        private String Coordinate2;
        @SerializedName("DateTime")
        @Expose
        private String DateTime;
        @SerializedName("Speed")
        @Expose
        private String Speed;
        @SerializedName("Port")
        @Expose
        private int Port;

        public MapDetails(String serialNumber, String coordinate1, String                 
         coordinate2, String dateTime, String speed, int port) {
            SerialNumber = serialNumber;
            Coordinate1 = coordinate1;
            Coordinate2 = coordinate2;
            DateTime = dateTime;
            Speed = speed;
            Port = port;
        }

        public String getSerialNumber() {
            return SerialNumber;
        }

        public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
            SerialNumber = serialNumber;
        }

        public String getCoordinate1() {
            return Coordinate1;
        }

        public void setCoordinate1(String coordinate1) {
            Coordinate1 = coordinate1;
        }

        public String getCoordinate2() {
            return Coordinate2;
        }

        public void setCoordinate2(String coordinate2) {
            Coordinate2 = coordinate2;
        }

        public String getDateTime() {
            return DateTime;
        }

        public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
            DateTime = dateTime;
        }

        public String getSpeed() {
            return Speed;
        }

        public void setSpeed(String speed) {
            Speed = speed;
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return Port;
        }

        public void setPort(int port) {
            Port = port;
        }

    }
```

this is my sqlite database ive like to retrieve:
[image]

this is the sample posting ive created at the top
[image]

but in my case, ive like to do is this one, getting the saved data from my database and send it like this,:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why only one is being sent is that you are sending outside of the while loop that traverses the Cursor, so only the last is sent.

That is you have :-

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ADDRESS = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_ADDRESS));
    PORT = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_PORT));
    TIMEINTERVAL=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_TIME_INTERVAL));
 }
```

So say the query extracted a Cursor with 10 rows as address 1,2,3....10 (for explantory purposes) then

The loop is entered ADDRESS is set to 1, the next iteration sets it to 2, the next to 3 ..... and finally ADDRESS is set to 10 (same for PORT and TIMEINTERVAL)

After the loop the data is sent so only one is sent (ADDRESS 10).

What you need is along the lines of :-

```
List<MapDetails> data = new ArrayList<>();
MapDetails mapDetails
Retrofit.Builder builder;
Retrofit retrofit;
Call<MapDetails> call;
Api locate;

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ADDRESS = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_ADDRESS));
    PORT = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_PORT));
    TIMEINTERVAL=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_TIME_INTERVAL));

    portInts=Integer.parseInt(PORT);
    mapDetails = new MapDetails(gg, lat, lon, well, "0", portInts);
    data.clear(); //<<<<<<<< remove previous entries if required????
    data.add(mapDetails);
    builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://" + ADDRESS + ":" + PORT) 
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    retrofit = builder.build();
    locate = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    call = locate.mapDetailLocation(data);     
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MapDetails>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MapDetails> call, Response<MapDetails> response) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "" + response,
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Action", null).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "" + t.getMessage(),
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Action", null).show();
     }
}
```

- ***Note*** the above is in-principle code. it has not been checked or tested and may therefore contain some errors.
- It may be that you can send an entire set e.g. **data** with populated in which case you may only need up to `data.add(mapDetails);` in the loop and then have the following code outside the loop.

Comment: sir sorry, i didnt add my database and testing.. ive just edit my post so that you can elaborate it :)

Comment: @JuliusAndaya What you've added doesn't appear to change anything. The answer still appears to indicate the issue and also includes a guide to fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, you need to send **JSONArray** as payload for the request. But, you made a little mistake while preparing payload from SQLite database. @Mike T pointed out that mistake in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53440137/5180017) to your question.

Follow these codes to fix the problem.

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper2 = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase db2 = databaseHelper2.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = databaseHelper2.retrieveSettingFromLocalDatabase(db2);

List<MapDetails> data = new ArrayList<>(); // declare ArrayList outside and before while loop

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ADDRESS = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_ADDRESS));
    PORT = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_PORT));
    TIMEINTERVAL = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SETTING_TIME_INTERVAL));

    // pass arguments to MapDetails class constructor

    portInts = Integer.parseInt(PORT);

    MapDetails mapDetails = new MapDetails(gg, lat, lon, well, "0", portInts); //Datas ive get to send in api

    // add prepared data to ArrayList

    data.add(mapDetails);
}

// and finally execute network call

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("http://" + ADDRESS + ":" + PORT) 
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

Api locate = retrofit.create(Api.class);

Call<MapDetails> call = locate.mapDetailLocation(data);     
call.enqueue(new Callback<MapDetails>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MapDetails> call, Response<MapDetails> response) {

        Snackbar.make(view, "" + response, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Action", null).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

        Snackbar.make(view, "" + t.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Action", null).show();

    }
});
```

**PS**: I'm not sure why are you taking `ADDRESS` and `PORT` from SQLite database. If they're same in every single row you don't need to take it from database right?

Comment: oww sorry, i have mistaken again sir, ive didn't show my full database.... upon my problem, the PORT and ADDRESS was from another dbTable,  on my problem side was this one "MapDetails mapDetails = new MapDetails(gg, lat, lon, well, "0", portInts)"... these data "gg,lat,lon,well,0,pointints" is static variable, geeting from the my map data and other string... but ive like just like to do was i will get data from database (5 sets of data like that) and send it all to the api... not just the one that ive retrived and send it to api...